# Multiple Symfony form types, all for same object, validate at once by faking submission

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony5

I have several FormTypes, all for the same entity type (Car, e.g.), each handles a different aspect (DoorsTyoe, EngineType, TrunkType, SeatsType). When the user has walked through all these forms, on different pages, I want to check before finally saving the results, once more all FormTypes.

So the idea was: Create a new FormType CarType, put all the different pieces on it (DoorsType, EngineType, ...), "fake a submit" and get the errors. But when I want to add the different "sub-forms", I cannot add them without specifying a "child name" for them. Is there any way around this? Right now, I create an array with all the child names, and have a the car object in a separate key:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
{
    $builder->add(
        'doors',
        DoorsType::class,
        [
            'getter' => function ($data, FormInterface $form): Car {
                return $data['theCar'];
            },
            'setter' => function (array $data, Car $submittedData, FormInterface $form): void {
                // just throw away what we get.
            },
        ],
    );
    
    // And so on for EngineType etc.
}
```

Then I call this with:

```
$fooData = [
    "doors" => "PLACEHOLDER",
    "engine" => "PLACEHOLDER",
    "theCar" => $car
];

$form = $this->formFactory->create($formType, $fooData, [
]);

$form->submit($fooData, true);

$errors = $form->getErrors(true, true);

dump($errors);

return $form->isValid();
```

My issue is the crazy structure with the $fooData array. I would prefer to work on $car only. When I change the DoorsType etc. to unmapped fields, the getters are not called so I assume they will not work at all?

Somehow I am missing a point...

Comment: Learned something...  $form->submit($fooData, true); All "guides" suggest putting $fooData=null or []. with false as second parameter, sub-forms do not get submitted (and therefore, not validated). With true as second parameter they get submitted but as there is no data, I am only validating a blank form.

Comment: Does the [`inherit_data`](https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/form/inherit_data_option.html) option solve your problem?

Comment: No it did not... The reason is that the submit event is not fired for forms with inherit_data.  In my case I found a function which converts the data structure to "post information", we then put this into the submit function. I did not find a solution without providing actual data.